# DMX Query For MS Association Rules

Tags: reporting-services

I am currently stuck in writing DMX Query because I am new to that.

I am using the query:

```
SELECT (NODE_SUPPORT),NODE_NAME, NODE_Caption  
FROM invoices.CONTENT  
WHERE NODE_TYPE = 7
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0fkO.png)

I don't want to show attribute value 'Existing' or 'Missing' in the result because i want to show these results in SSRS chart.
We can filter that in MS Association Rules Viewer in SSAS but
If anybody knows how can we filter that using DMX? Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.